# Button array For tic tac toe Assignment

Tags: c#, arrays, button, tic-tac-toe

I have an assignment and with this assignment I should create a game called "tic tac toe".
at this assignment w are requested to create something like;

private Button [,] ticTacToeButtons

I dont know how to use it. I create 9 button with Windows form application and at the background I tried to connect this buttons with this array but I am not sure which elements can add to this array.

Comment: You need to add the button controls to that array

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of buttons

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
       buttons[i] = new Button();
       buttons[i].Text = "";
       Controls.Add(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I learned it. I hope this answer help everyone;

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ticTacToeButtons = new Button[3, 3] { { this.button1, this.button2, this.button3 }, { this.button4, this.button5, this.button6 }, { this.button7, this.button8, this.button9 } } ;
        }
        private Button[,] ticTacToeButtons;